# Function returns as error (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kinda new to Python, and I would like to ask a question :

```
def spam(a):
    a = 1 + a
    return a
spam(21)
print(spam)
input()
```

After running it, the output is  `function spam at 0x021B24F8`. Shouldn't the output be `22`? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your function, i.e. `spam` is returning a value. You need to accept the value returned by the function and store it in a different variable as in

```
s = spam(21)
print(s)
```

Here, you will store the returning value in the variable `s` which you will print it out.

After making the correction, the program will print as expected as in

```
22
```

Note - As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278434/function-returns-as-error-python-3#comment46754958_29278454), having a single statement `print(spam(21))` also works as `spam(21)` will return `22` to the `print` function which will then print out the value for you!

Comment: Or simply `print(spam(21))`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, Have edited the answer to include your suggestion